# Native bug reporting in Android extendng force close dialog?

Tags: android, unhandled-exception, bug-reporting

I have seen a new native force close dialog with a new button "Send report" on several apps.

[image]

How can I get it for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to [Android Application Error Reports](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html) , which is new to Android 2.2. If you need it for previous versions of the OS, you can use [acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/).

Comment: Well, does it mean I have to set minSDK version to API 8 (2.2) to make it work? I am pretty sure that I have seen it on my 2.1 device

Comment: Went with ACRA now. Will mark this question as answered, when my previous comment is answered.

Comment: I haven't used Error Reports so I can't answer your comment. I believe however that setting the minSDK to 8 won't be needed. If you have seen something like this in an 2.1 device, it was probably ACRA.

Comment: I am using ACRA now - the best solution to me. You are probably right. That was ACRA mostlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, some 2.1 devices like the Nexus One (and maybe the Motorola Droid) had the "native" Android Error Reports activated before being updated to 2.2.

Comment: I think I have seen that on the Google Places Directory App on my Motorola Milestone